# Difference between transformations written as $TOT^{\dagger}$ and as $TOT^{-1}$ in quantum matrix mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra, observables

When we write quantum operators in matrix form, we perform transformations. I have seen that at some points the transformation $T$ of a matrix $O$ is written as, for example,

1. $O\to TOT^{\dagger}$
2. $O\to TOT^{-1}$

What is the physical meaning of these two types of transformations?

Comment: If $T$ is unitary, then $T^\dagger=T^{-1}$.

Comment: This also holds if $T$ is anti-unitary.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I am used to unitary quantum mechanics and always write transformations with $T^\dagger$. I found an article that writes "we perform an orthonormal transformation in terms of $T=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$" and then they perform transformation with $TOT^{-1}$. It made me wonder what is difference between $T^{-1}$ and $T^{\dagger}$. Because here $T^{-1}\ne T^\dagger$

Comment: Key search phrase: 'similarity transformation'.